# How to use Serial module in Phoenix application?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm newbie in elixir. I want to init and use module in Phoenix app, for example I found nice module [Serial](https://hex.pm/packages/serial), can I init it and store instance once as worker and use it in eg. Controller? Based on Serial module, How to use start_link, and then send_data in controller/channel?

Comment: There are several aspects to using a module in app in Elixir.  Maybe you could narrow your question a little?  For example, do you know how to add the module into your mix.exs file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the author of the module. I have updated the README to include some basic examples.

You can use it in a Phoenix-based web application, I do it in one of my projects.

It is best to create another process (a worker, possibly named, somewhere in your supervision tree) which starts and owns the serial port, to abstract the low-level communication and to receive and process incoming data. You can then have the controller communicate with this worker through your higher-level API.